# can I pass observable as function parameter?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Can I pass observable to function as a parameter ?
I have two observables that get data from backend and I need to filter them out by a lot of conditions.
To do not repeat myself I thought about function that will filter observable data and return already filtered one. There will be couple of combineLatest inside as I will be reacting to action streams (values selected on UI).
I came up with something like:

```
    const data1$ = this.service.getData('first');
    const data2$ = this.service.getData('second');

    filterData(input$: Observable<string>) : Observable<string> {

        const filtered$ = combineLatest(input$, this.service.selectedFiltersData$).pipe(...filtering...taping and so on...)
        const filteredBySomethingElse$(filtered$, this.service.anotherSelectedFilters.pipe(...filtering...taping and so on...)

      return filteredBySomethingElse$;
    }

    const filtered1$ = this.filterData(data1$);
    const filtered2$ = this.filterData(data2$);
```

Example is extremely simplified :)
Is that a good practice ?

Comment: is a object  ? You can use pipe and pluc from rxjs library

Comment: "Can" you? Sure. Is it a good practice? That's an opinion (and therefore [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic))

Comment: It seems to be fine.

Comment: It seems to me a little bit odd as I'm just starting with observables

Answer (score 3):

You could use a more declarative approach. Something like this:

```
  // Filtered products
  filteredProducts$ = combineLatest([
    this.allProducts$,
    this.filterAction$])
    .pipe(
      // Perform the filtering
      map(([products, filter]) =>
        this.performFilter(products, filter))
    );
```

Then you don't need to pass Observables into procedures. The code that actually does the filtering takes in the products and filter, not their associated observables.

PLUS: The pipe operations will re-execute every time a new value is emitted into either stream.

See this for more information: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z76QlSpYcck